# class definition not found error on jboss 6 but the class is present in the jar file

Tags: jakarta-ee, jar, classpath, noclassdeffounderror, jboss6.x

I created a jar file containing some APIs for distribution.

- My jar file is added to the `lib` folder of the project.
- While trying to create the object of the class it throws `ClassDefinitionNotFound` exception
- I tested the jar by creating a demo project in eclipse and everything works fine.
- The same jar file can be used by my program when kept in the `deploy` folder of JBOSS